# c# InnerException of socket in XamlParseException

Tags: c#, sockets, exception

I have been developing a basic c# chat application for practice with networking in c# and have built a fairly stable build for the application however I came across a really strange thing when I started a second instance of the application in my visual studio debugger. While the first instance was running flawlessly the second instance gave a `XamlParseException` in the `InitializeComponents()` function. It had an inner exception of *Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted*.

- What confuses me is that all the working and creating and managing of sockets is being done in subsequent lines of code on back end, then how is the simple parsing of xaml giving rise to this exception (which parsed flawlessly in case of the first instance of application which is already running).
- Even if the program needs to have an exception thrown due to conflicting sockets, it should be thrown later(while binding for TCP/ while sending for UDP) so I can debug which transmission is throwing the exception, but in this case it fails at the first line `InitializeComponents()` only.

Thanks a lot in advance and please edit the title/content to anything more appropriate if needed. If code is needed please comment and I will provide it.

EDIT- Googling gave no possible relation between the two `XamlParseException` and the only one usage of socket exception. The `XamlParseException` was linked to errors in xaml as apparent while in case of socket exception I was due to conflicting sockets on same port.

Here's the XAML-code:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChatApp"
    xmlns:Conv="clr-namespace:Converters" xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:custom_commands"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" x:Name="wnd" x:Class="ChatApp.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="700" MinWidth="550" MinHeight="450" ContentRendered="sort">
<Window.Resources>
    <Conv:sub x:Key="converter_sub" />
    <Conv:margin_sub x:Key="converter_margin_sub" />
    <Conv:button_margin_sub x:Key="converter_button_margin_sub" />
    <Conv:mul x:Key="converter_mul" />
    <Conv:mul_and_sub x:Key="converter_mul_and_sub" />
    <Conv:sub_and_mul x:Key="converter_sub_and_mul" />
    <Conv:tab_width_calc x:Key="tab_calc" />
    <Conv:messagebox_width_calc x:Key="messagebox_calc" />
    <Conv:join_nick_and_ip x:Key="join_nick_and_ip" />
    <Conv:subtract_two_multibindings x:Key="subtract_two_multibindings" />
    <Conv:status_bar_text x:Key="status_bar_text" />
    <Storyboard x:Key="show_log" >
        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="0,0,0,0" DecelerationRatio=".9" Duration="0:0:0.8"/>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="hide_log" >
        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="0,0,-210,0" DecelerationRatio=".9" Duration="0:0:0.8"/>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="show_rect" >
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.1" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="hide_rect" >
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="commands:custom_commands.exit" Executed="ExitCommand_Executed"/>
    <CommandBinding Command="commands:custom_commands.connect_new" Executed="manuallyConnectCommand_Executed"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Opacity="0" Panel.ZIndex="-1" Name="hide_log_rect" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ConverterParameter=25, Converter={StaticResource converter_sub}, ElementName=wnd}" Stroke="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=wnd}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Mouse.MouseUp="hide_log"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Opacity="0" Panel.ZIndex="-1" Name="lose_searcharea_focus_rect" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ConverterParameter=25, Converter={StaticResource converter_sub}, ElementName=wnd}" Stroke="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.RowSpan="2" Mouse.MouseUp="lose_searcharea_focus_rect_MouseUp">
        <Rectangle.Width>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource subtract_two_multibindings}" ConverterParameter="10">
                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="wnd"/>
                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="status_area"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Rectangle.Width>
    </Rectangle>

    <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Panel.ZIndex="1" x:Name="menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width= "{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=wnd}">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" Command="commands:custom_commands.exit" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Options">
            <MenuItem Header="Connect Manually" Command="commands:custom_commands.connect_new"/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="toggle_server" Header="Server Running" Click="toggle_server_status" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True"/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="toggle_broadcast" Header="Server Broadcasting" Click="toggle_broadcasting" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <StatusBar Panel.ZIndex="51" Height="20" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=wnd}">
        <StatusBarItem Margin="{Binding ElementName=wnd, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource converter_margin_sub}, ConverterParameter=260}">
            <TextBlock FontSize="11.5" Text="{Binding ElementName=toggle_server, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource status_bar_text}, ConverterParameter=0}"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
        <Separator/>
        <StatusBarItem>
            <TextBlock FontSize="11.5" Text="{Binding ElementName=toggle_broadcast, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource status_bar_text},ConverterParameter= 1}"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
    <Grid Panel.ZIndex="3" x:Name="grid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ConverterParameter=25, Converter={StaticResource converter_sub}, ElementName=wnd}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=wnd}">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" MaxWidth="228.61272" MinWidth="140.63584"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Canvas Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="status_area" FocusManager.GotFocus="search_area_GotFocus">
            <ListView x:Name="listView" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ConverterParameter=103, Converter={StaticResource converter_sub}, ElementName=grid1}" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="43" MaxWidth="210" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ConverterParameter=0.2857143-20, Converter={StaticResource converter_mul_and_sub}, ElementName=grid1}">
                <ListView.Resources>
                    <ContextMenu x:Key="context_menu">
                        <MenuItem Header="Connect" Click="broadcast_list_connect">
                            <MenuItem.Tag>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource join_nick_and_ip}">
                                    <Binding Path="nick"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ip"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </MenuItem.Tag>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ListView.Resources>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource context_menu}">
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ConverterParameter=10, Converter={StaticResource converter_sub}, ElementName=listView}"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding nick}">
                            <GridViewColumnHeader x:Name="sort_header" Tag="Name" Click="sort" >
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"><Run Text="Nick                     "/></TextBlock>
                            </GridViewColumnHeader>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
            <TextBox x:Name="search_textbox" Height="28" Canvas.Left="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Search.." Canvas.Top="5" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ConverterParameter=0.2857143-20, Converter={StaticResource converter_mul_and_sub}, ElementName=grid1}" MaxWidth="210" KeyUp="search_textbox_KeyUp"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <TabControl SelectionChanged="tab_SelectionChanged" x:Name="tabControl" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ConverterParameter=65, Converter={StaticResource converter_sub}, ElementName=grid1}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ConverterParameter=0.7142857-228.61272, Converter={StaticResource tab_calc}, ElementName=grid1}" Canvas.Top="5"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
    <Canvas Panel.ZIndex="51" x:Name="log_canvas" Background="CornflowerBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ConverterParameter=35, Converter={StaticResource converter_sub}, ElementName=grid1}" Margin="0,0,-210,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210" Grid.RowSpan="2" Opacity="0.9">
        <Menu Height="25">
            <MenuItem Width="31" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="-210,0,0,0" x:Name="log_menu_button" Click="toggle_log" >
                <MenuItem.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="2" ShadowDepth="2"/>
                </MenuItem.Effect>
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="Resources/menu.png" Margin="3,0,0,2"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <ListBox x:Name="log" Background="White" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ConverterParameter=25, Converter={StaticResource converter_sub}, ElementName=log_canvas}" Canvas.Top="25" Width="210"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

and a small I suppose relevant part of the c# main class constructor code:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        get_machine_name();              

        server_start();

        receive_broadcasts();

        Thread thread = new Thread(() => update_available_clients());
        thread.Name = "Bradcast List Update";
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
        .
        .
        .
        .
}
```

Here the exception is thrown in line 1 InitializeComponents() only, not even proceeding to subsequent lines where actual functions like server_start() which actually interact with sockets are called.

The call stack:

```
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, System.Uri baseUri)   Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, System.Uri baseUri) Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext parserContext, object parent, bool closeStream)    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext pc)    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Uri resourceLocator, bool bSkipJournaledProperties)   Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application._ctor.AnonymousMethod__0(object unused)    Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()   Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(object state)  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()   Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)   Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)  Unknown
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore)   Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window window)  Unknown
ChatApp.exe!ChatApp.App.Main()  C#
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) Unknown
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()    Unknown
```

and the stacktrace for outer XamlParseException was the string:

> "   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)"

for the socket inner exception the stacktrace string was:

> "   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient..ctor(Int32 port, AddressFamily family)\r\n   at ChatApp.MainWindow..ctor() in C:\Users\Kaustubh\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ChatApplication\ChatApp\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 100"

Thanks and if you need any more code, please tell.

Comment: It would help if you pasted some code and a stack trace.

Comment: Codes and stack trace added. Please tell if you need more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a data member initialised as

```
private UdpClient broadcast_receiver= new UdpClient(15069);
```

and it was failing to bind to the port and hence the error but since the members were being initialised along with the InitiliseComponents() call so was this exception being thrown.

Comment: Excactly. You answered your own question!

Comment: Thanks a lot, took a while figuring it out, btw why did u delete your answer it was dead on too and perhaps a little more explanatory in debugging further exceptions

Comment: I made a mistake in the explanation, and since you answered it yourself, I thought you could explain better. It's rather self-explanatory, in the end, and I would only complicate it. You were only confused that you didn't get the exception you expected, because it was 'wrapped up'. I knew as soon as you pasted your stack trace that you'd see it.